# filteredArrayUsingPredicate returning nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm building a application that I have to compare if an hour is between an inicial and a final hour that I'm saving like seconds in CoreData with the type Integer64. To compare this hours I'm using filteredArrayUsingPredicate with this predicate:

```
NSMutableArray *allDiscounts = (NSMutableArray *)[[DataStack defaultStack] fetchAllDiscounts];    
NSMutableArray *hoursResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
    NSNumber *timeInSeconds = [[DataStack defaultStack] stringToSeconds:string];

NSLog(@"allDiscounts count: %lu",(unsigned long)[allDiscounts count]);
NSLog(@"inicial time; %@",[[allDiscounts objectAtIndex:0] inicialTime]);
NSLog(@"final time; %@",[[allDiscounts objectAtIndex:0] finalTime]);
NSLog(@"time in seconds: %d", [timeInSeconds intValue]);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inicialTime <= %@ AND %@ <= finalTime",timeInSeconds,timeInSeconds];
[hoursResults addObjectsFromArray:[allDiscounts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
NSLog(@"hoursResults count: %lu", (unsigned long)[discountResults count]);
```

and adding the result to another NSMutableArray, but I always getting 0 with result.

this is the log that i'm getting:

```
2015-03-15 16:05:09.883 Vanttage[9342:662093] allDiscounts count: 87
2015-03-15 16:05:09.883 Vanttage[9342:662093] inicial time; 68400
2015-03-15 16:05:09.883 Vanttage[9342:662093] final time; 82800
2015-03-15 16:05:09.884 Vanttage[9342:662093] time in seconds: 72000
2015-03-15 16:05:09.885 Vanttage[9342:662093] hoursResults count: 0
```

What I'm doing wrong? Hope you can help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inicialTime <= %d AND %d <= finalTime",[timeInSeconds intValue],[timeInSeconds intValue]];` assuming timeInSeconds is an NSNumber

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line.  What type is timeInSeconds and what is its value?

Comment: Also, when you put the breakpoint in, what does allDiscounts contain?

Comment: I'll update the post with some more informations that I'm getting with the log.

Comment: Man, I saw my mistake. I'm printing the variable discountsResults instead the hoursResults. All this time I'm getting the wrong variable.I think i'm tired. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out